# How do I see Cmake messages in bitbake output?

Tags: cmake, yocto, bitbake

I am building [libiio](https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libiio) for my yocto image using [this](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/57509/) libiio recipe from `meta-oe`.

In the library's [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libiio/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) file, there are lines like:

```auto
message(STATUS "cmake version: ${CMAKE_VERSION}")
[...]
message(SEND_ERROR "IPv6 is not available in your system.")
[...]
message(WARNING "Missing pkgbuild or productbuild: OSX installer won't be created.")
```

However, when I run `bitbake libiio` I do not see any messages

How do I set up my yocto/bitbake environment in a way I can see these messages and errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `inherit` cmake in your recipe or you don't, I assume that `cmake` command is executed during `do_configure`, in Yocto, task logs are saved in the working directory of the recipe under:

```
WORKDIR/temp/log.do_configure
```

So, follow the following:

1. Get the working directory of your recipe

```bash
bitbake -e libiio | grep ^WORKDIR=
```

2. Change directory to that path
3. Check the content of `temp/log.do_configure`

If you want to see them directly through the `bitbake` command use `-v` option:

> -v, --verbose         Enable tracing of shell tasks (with 'set -x').
> Also
> print bb.note(...) messages to stdout (in addition to
> writing them to ${T}/log.do_)

```
bitbake -v -c do_configure libiio
```